# How to affect a property of an element in an IEnumerable?

Tags: c#, dictionary, ienumerable, immutability

I've got the behavior where I pick out an element from a dictionary (the value is an enumerable of custom type) and change a value in it. However, when I step through the process, I see that the value stored doesn't get effective in the end, so I'm guessing that I'm manipulating *a copy* of that I'm intending.

```
Dictionary<String, IEnumerable<Custom>> myDictionary = ...;
String key = "key";
myDictionary[key]
  .First(element => element.Origin == "beep")
  .Value = "hazaa";
```

I'd expect the above to actually affect the property *myDictionary* but as it seems while debugging, the original value is unchanged. My conclusion is that *First* gives me a working **copy** of the element (or that *Value* does that).

How can I force my *hazaa* into it?

The custom class is very simple.

```
class Custom 
{
  public String Origin { get; set; }
  public String Value {get; set; }
}
```

The actual type of the elements in the dictionary is: *{Name = "d__711" FullName = "System.Linq.Enumerable+d__711[[Configurator.Custom, Configurator, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null]]"}*

Comment: Whay MyDictionary is? If, by case, [] returns an IEnumerable of objects with an untyped Object property named Value... (First() does not return a copy, of course unless T is a struct).

Comment: What's the concrete type of the enumerable? How is it generated? Your code would work if it were a simple collection like `List<T>` for instance. I guess your probles is caused by a lazily generated sequence.

Comment: Is `Custom` perhaps a struct instead of a class? Your code sample shows a class, but perhaps you simplified this detail out when you posted this?

Comment: @AdrianoRepetti *Custom* is a class. As for the type, I though it was implictly obvious. Sorry - my misstake. Updated the question.

Comment: @LucasTrzesniewski See the edit. The type is *IEnumerable*, so the laziness might have to do with it...

Comment: @KonradViltersten yes, I saw edit. Who knows, it always MAY be a custom dictionary/map. Are you sure isn't just something wrong about what you see in debugging? It has to work as is.

Comment: @Konrad that's why I asked for the *concrete type*. `IEnumerable<T>` can be anything ranging from a list to a SQL query to an infinite sequence to a *format C: on first enumeration* ;) What does `myDictionary[key].GetType()` return?

Comment: If I assign *hazaa* programmatically, it doesn't show in the output file. However, if I edit the value in the debugger "by hand", it gets through to the file. So it's the assignment that fail. Might have to do with the lazy generation but still... Got me confused...

Comment: @LucasTrzesniewski Yeah, my bad for not realizing the ambiguity. Sorry. The type is *IEnumerable<Custom>* (the bells and whistles cut off for readibility).

Comment: @KonradViltersten: That is still the interface. What is the real class type of the `IEnumerable`?

Comment: That's still not good enough ;) What does `myDictionary[key].GetType()` return? It cannot return an interface like `IEnumerable<Custom>`. I'm asking for the class implementing `IEnumerable<Custom>`.

Comment: @KonradViltersten Just to show you that it does work on `IEnumerable` in general: http://ideone.com/uCNwBP

Comment: Strangely. On my machine this code works fine. The element value are changing.

Comment: @LucasTrzesniewski Oh, this... My confusion, mate. When I store that into a *Type* type variable I get this atrocity: *{Name = "<ConcatIterator>d__71`1" FullName = "System.Linq.Enumerable+<ConcatIterator>d__71`1[[Configurator.Custom, Configurator, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null]]"}*

Comment: @PatrickHofman Right, my baaad... Please see the comment to Lucas. It's something less pleasant for the eyes that I get...

Comment: @KonradViltersten: You need to show more code. Can you make a piece of code we can pase into VS directly and see the problem?

Comment: Yep, that's a lazy enumerable, but unfortunately the only thing I can tell from that is that you've used a `.Concat` call in the last place of the chain. Just call `.ToList()` on it and then store *that* in the dictionary. This should solve your problem.

Comment: @PatrickHofman I can't. I'm bouncing around with some weird legacy stuff that I can't access the source code to. And the person who's developed that is known to be as competent as willing to share the wisdom. Very little, that is.   :)

Comment: @LucasTrzesniewski Good call, dude. That was it. Please put it as a reply so I can accept it as an answer. Stupid laziness... :)